# A projection error estimation in Sobolev space of Fractional order (1D)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Pi_0$ be the $L_2$ projector that maps $u \in L_2(I)$ to a constant function, where $I$ is taken as the interval $(0,1)$.

I would like to find an error estimation for $u \in H^{1/2}(I)$, such as

$$
\|u-\Pi_0 u\|_{L_2(I)} \le C |u|_{H^{1/2}(I)}
$$

Could anyone give me a hint on concrete value or upper bound for the constant $C$?

I have tried to transfer the constant determination problem into an eigenvalue problem.

Let $V:=\{ v \in H^{1/2}(I), \int_I vdx=0 \}$. Then the eigenvalue problem is:

Find $u\in V$ and $\lambda \in R$ such that,
$$
(u,v)_{H^{1/2}(I)} = \lambda (u,v)_{L_2(I)} \mbox{ for } v\in V\:.
$$

It seems that the eigen-function can be characterized by the following equation.
$$
\int_I \frac{u(y)}{(x-y)^2} dy = \lambda u(x)\:.
$$

But, I cannot go on to find the value or the lower bound of the minimal eigenvalue in need.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.